# Modification of Set Function in Construction of Lebesgue Measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose in the construction of Lebesgue measure we replace the set function $\mu((a,b))=b-a$ with $\mu((a,b))=\sqrt{b-a}$.  What can we say about $\mu^*$ and the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets?  Certainly $\mu^*(a,b)=\sqrt{b-a}$, and the $\sigma$-algebra consists at least of sets of Lebesgue measure $0$, but what more can be said?

Answer (score 0):

In such case
$$
\sqrt{2}=\mu\big((0,2)\big)=\mu\big((0,1)\big)+\mu\big(\{1\}\big)+\mu\big((1,2)\big)=1+\mu\big(\{1\}\big)+1.
$$
Apparently, such a measure can not be positive, and, it is not hard to see, that it can not be a measure either.

Comment: Certainly it cannot be a measure, but can we say anything more about the values of the outer measure on the power set and the sets in the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: I'm interested in this problem. If we define an outer measure $\mu^*$ in the subsets of $[0,1]$ as $\mu^*(A) = \inf\{\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sqrt{b_n-a_n} : A \subset \bigcup [a_n,b_n]\}$, it can be shown that no interval is then $\mu^*$-measurable. I would like to extend this to the fact that if $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, it has to be that either $\mu^*(A)$ or $\mu^*([0,1] \setminus A)$ is zero. Any insight?